# I'm looking for an equation based on an excel-graph and an model-equation (=a + b cos(alpha - phi).

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a table with factors who can transform a regional windspeed to a local windspeed. The factors are calculated for different wind direction and speed sectors as shown in the table (fig. 2). Now I would like to obtain from the plotted graph (fig. 1) a function that theoretically fits the egg-shaped graph in the form of "a + b cos(alpha - phi)".

What I already know:
a = average of the factors (for sure)
b = something to do with the amplitude (?)
alpha = a wind angle I suppose (?)
phi = something to do with max and min (like here at 0° and 180° I would say)

It may be that this only goes for a well-defined speed sector, like 6-8 m/s

Thank you in advance!
Sebastian

[plotted graph of the table with factors (fig. 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndsDn.png)

[table with factors per winddirection en windspeed sector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loGgE.png)

Comment: It is customary to ask to find what steps you took in helping yourself before demanding consultation help etc. from here,

Comment: @Narasimham I have calculated the factors myself, but my promotor wants an equation out of the graph, but I haven't a clue how to begin. The things 'I know' are suggestions from my supervisor.